# Temporal paradox: Migrated question locked before closure

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, timestamps

A recently [migrated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240164/great-questions-and-answers-in-stackoverflow) showed the following log:

- migrated to meta.stackoverflow.com 43 secs ago
- locked by Community♦ 42 secs ago
- closed as belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com by zombat, cletus, Thomas Owens, Reed Copsey, bdonlan 43 secs ago

How was it locked before it was closed?

Comment: is this a serious question

Comment: @Barak, well, it's a bug, anyway. It's not a very severe bug, but reporting a non-severe bug at least makes a note of it somewhere, in case it turns out to be more severe than initially expected. I don't really care if it's fixed, in other words, but it should be _known_.

Comment: The key word you overlooked is "ago".

Comment: I think it's funny that you're reporting a minor timing issue when the post in question has a much larger bug - it was migrated twice.

Comment: **temporal paradox**... wow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been errors where the clocks on the database server and web server aren't exactly in sync, leading to issues where something was posted "-3 seconds ago", so this could be something like that.

Also, look at the times - it was locked 42 seconds ago, but the rest happened 1 second earlier, at 43 seconds ago. So it was really locked *after* the post was closed and migrated. This is corroborated by the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1240164/list):

> **Post Locked** by Community♦ occurred **6 mins ago**
>
> **Post Migrated** to meta.stackoverflow.com by zombat, cletus, Thomas Owens, Reed Copsey, bdonlan occurred **6 mins ago**
>
> **Post Closed** as "belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com" by zombat, cletus, Thomas Owens, Reed Copsey, bdonlan occurred **6 mins ago**

Comment: Doh. Misread the times. That would do it :)

Comment: there shouldn't be time sync issues any more, see http://serverfault.com/questions/1406/windows-server-unable-to-synchronize-ntp-time-reliably